# joomla publish menu item under program control

Tags: php, joomla, publish, menuitem

I need to control the publication of a menu or a menu item under program control.  I plan to write a ChronoForms form that will allow a user to nominate a date on which a menu or item is published and then another date on which it is unpublished. Then use php code to set those dates into the menu module definitions.

Reading some answers here I suspect that I can do that by changing a database record but that that is not the best/preferred way - I should use the API.

Can anyone get me started on that, please?

Regards
Nick

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there isn't a publish start/end date for a joomla menu item. So there is no api to do what you want.

The way i would do it is to store the start/end date in a separate table then create a schedule in mysql to check every day if a menu item should be published or not. And update the "published" field in table _menu accordingly.

Sorry if this is not the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks tomjm.  I think that I have just about concluded that I need to shift the menu items to their own menu.  I reckon I then have a better chance since there is a start end publish date.

Answer (score 0):

There is a extension called Article anywhere that let you import an article into another article. You can then set start/end publish date for these articles.